# Finding the centroid of a solid region using triple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been struggling with this textbook problem for some time now and thought I'd seek assistance. The question asks me to find the centroid of a solid region bounded by these two equations:

$$z = \frac{h}{r} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, $$
and
$$z = h $$
I noticed the conical shape, and that $\bar x$ = $\bar y$ = $0$.
What I struggle with is setting up the limits of integration properly? Is a polar coordinate system worth it in the context of this problem? (dzdrd$\theta$)

Comment: Yes, you should use cylindrical coordinates.